# How to scale and/or move textures relative to other textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

To give an example of this question: Imagine you have some bricks, after UV unwrapping, you apply a brick textures to your wall, you also however, want water drops on your bricks as if it has been raining (please don't take this example literally and give some reason for why there is another way to do this, it is just to introduce the problem).

So you apply your water droplet texture, but there is a problem, in the UV editor, you can only move the representation of the mesh, not the images themselves, so if the bricks are too large, you can scale up the mesh, but then the water droplets will be too large as well, if you scale the mesh back down so the water droplets are fine, the bricks become too large again.

So how do I scale or move the textures in relation to each other, I haven't found a way and have been searching around all the tools and dropdowns in the UI but can't seem to find a solution. If anyone has an answer, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Option A: Use different UV maps for each texture Option B: Scale the texture at material level through nodes

Comment: Which nodes can I use?

Comment: You can put a `Vector > Mapping` node between the `Texture Coordinate` node and your texture and adjust the scale. For UVs, you'll (usually) only use the X and Y scale.